# How to show a pop window of jsp page using javascript based on time?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I want to create a JSP page. In which I want to display a pop up window for every 10 secs. Also I want to enter a value to check the authentication in that pop up window itself. How to do it?

```
<tr> <td> I VALUE : <input type="text" name="t1" /></td> </tr> <tr> <td> F VALUE : <input type="text" name="t2" /> </tr> <tr><td><input type="submit" name="b1" value="CHECK...!" />
```

this is my jscript

```
    function validateForm() 
{ long delay = 10*1000; // delay in ms : 10 * 1000 ms = 10 sec. 

LoopTask task = new LoopTask(); 
Timer timer = new Timer("TaskName"); 
public void start() 
{ timer.cancel(); 
timer = new Timer("TaskName"); 
public void run() { popitup();
 } 
function popitup(url) 
{ newwindow=window.open('localhost:8080/Authentication/…); 
if (window.focus) 
{newwindow.focus();
} return false; 
} } } </script>
```

Comment: <tr>
  <td> I VALUE : <input type="text" name="t1" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td> F  VALUE : <input type="text" name="t2" />
 </tr>
 <tr><td><input type="submit" name="b1" value="CHECK...!" />

Comment: this is my jscript

<script>
function validateForm()
{
 

     long delay = 10*1000; // delay in ms : 10 * 1000 ms = 10 sec.
     LoopTask task = new LoopTask();
     Timer timer = new Timer("TaskName");

     public void start() {
     timer.cancel();
     timer = new Timer("TaskName");
    
     public void run() {
      
       
       popitup();
  
   
 }
     
 

  
function popitup(url) 
{
 newwindow=window.open('http://localhost:8080/Authentication/pop.jsp','name','height=200,width=150');
 if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus();}
 return false;
}
     }
}

</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to do new window where you get alert

//newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function startTime()
{
var today=new Date();
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();
// add a zero in front of numbers<10
m=checkTime(m);
s=checkTime(s);
if((parseInt(s)%10)==0)
alert("hello");// here alert change as  popup     
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
t=setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}

function checkTime(i)
{
if (i<10)
  {
  i="0" + i;
  }
return i;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">
<div id="txt"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. And How to display jsp page each time like pop up window

Comment: you want to show the jsp page in popup window for Authentication.Am I right?

Comment: Please use this line by removing alert and change url as your jsp url window.open('http://www.roseindia.net/javascript/pop-up.shtml','name','height=200,width=150');